# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I have seen a lot of these issues about the error below:
"[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)" but all the solutions are not solving my problem
I have followed all the instructions ditto, adding dependencies and what not. my build.gradles are ok but when I run I still get the error. this worked for me a month ago but now I don;t know what is happening this month.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50498/Z0uovONnF5A=/ws
Syncing files to device AOSP on IA Emulator...
E/flutter ( 8435): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter ( 8435): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter ( 8435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8435): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 8435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8435): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 8435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8435): #3      main (package:kp_app/main.dart:8:3)
E/flutter ( 8435): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8435):
```

This is my main.dart as you can see I have followed instructions, I did this last month no problem this month I try again, problem

```
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));


  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: const [
      Locale('en'),
      Locale('ar'),
      Locale('es'),
      Locale('fr'),
      Locale('de'),
      Locale('it'),
      Locale('pt'),
      Locale('ru'),
      Locale('zh'),
      Locale('ja'),
      Locale('hi'),
      Locale('sw')
    ],
    path: 'assets/translations',
    fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),

    //Default language
    startLocale: const Locale('en'),
    useOnlyLangCode: true,
    child: const NewApp(),
  ));
}

class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: const Center(child: Text('My New APp')),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my app level build.gradle and as you see it is intact

```
//plugins {
//    id "com.android.application"
//    id "kotlin-android"
//    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
//    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//apply plugin: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'

android {
    namespace "com.prowebsolutions.kp_app"
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.prowebsolutions.kp_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 28
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 31
//        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

This is also my project level build.gradle intact

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello is the Google services version try downgrade to 4.3.15
Other solution is migrate to buildscript to plugin block check the next:

File -> android/settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    plugins {
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" version "1.0.0" apply false
    }
}

include ":app"

apply from: "${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

File -> android/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.15' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.9' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

File -> android/app/build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'    
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.test_app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion localProperties.getProperty('flutter.minSdkVersion')
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

File -> android/local.properties

```
#Add your Android SDK path    
sdk.dir=D:\\Users\\Alex\\Sdk
#Add your Flutter path SDK  
flutter.sdk=D:\\Users\\Alex\\Flutter 
flutter.minSdkVersion=24
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

Finally execute `flutter clean` after `flutter pub get --no-example`

And check `google-services.json` file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Google services version downgrade to 4.3.15 from the answer of [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11141889/alex) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
i tried @Alex solution but got this. 
Exception: [!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running `flutter create -t app <app-directory>` and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project.

the best solution for this is use Firebase Cli method to connect with firebase project which needs Node.js cli , firebase cli, git and few more things but its the best method. 
Another ways is just add these two files and run
android/build.gradle
    buildscript {
      dependencies {
        // ... other dependencies
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
      }
    }

android/app/build.gradle
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded com.google.gms.google-services from 4.4.0 to 4.3.14. It was a used version of the application. Try to use valid version for your application.

```
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.14" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "2.9.9" apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error. After downgrading from 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1' to 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15' (as someone suggested here), it worked.